# Not displaying any button inside the scene

Tags: javafx

> its a simple javafx program thal will be switching between the two scenes.
>   program compiles fine but not showing any component inside the scene.
>   i've used two layouts, two buttons and two scenes.
>   assume that all the necessary packages were imported.
>   Source code: github.com/tmtanzeel/javafx/Program5.java

```
public class Program5 extends Application {
  Button button1;
  Button button2;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  button1=new Button();
  button2=new Button(); 

  button1.setText("Yes");
  button2.setText("No");

  StackPane layout1=new StackPane();
  layout1.getChildren().add(button1);

  StackPane layout2=new StackPane();
  layout2.getChildren().add(button1);

  Scene scene1=new Scene(layout1, 450,250);
  Scene scene2=new Scene(layout2, 250, 450);

  button1.setOnAction(e -> {
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
  });

  button2.setOnAction(e -> {
    primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
  });

  primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
  primaryStage.setTitle("Window-1");
  primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you try `primaryStage.pack();` ?

Comment: No. I haven't. Code is there on my github: tmtanzeel/javafx/Program5.java

Comment: please don't shout (aka: all uppercase letters - its unreadable)!

Comment: @PrimaAlessandro there is no pack method - or what do I miss?

Comment: there's no control in scene1, because you add button1 to second layout (which removes it from first)

Comment: rookie mistake. my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some syntax errors but this works you were previously setting the same scene so it doing what it was told it was swtiching to the same scene and the you were only adding button 1 to both screens

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button1 = new Button();
        Button button2 = new Button();

        button1.setText("Yes");
        button2.setText("No");

        StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
        layout1.getChildren().add(button1);

        StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
        layout2.getChildren().add(button2); //This should be button2

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 450, 250);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 250, 450);

        button1.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2)); //You set the wrong scene here

        button2.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene1)); //And here

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Window-1");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```